# Why do I need a delay when creating an Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a multi-line ListView using the method that many folks have blogged about - create an ArrayList> and add items to it, create a SimpleAdapter, then call setListAdapter. My (abbreviated) code looks something like this:

```
final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> temp;

for (ProviderResults pr : providerArrayList){
    temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp.put("providerName",pr.getProviderName());
    temp.put("providerAddress",pr.getAddress());
    temp.put("providerCityStateZip",pr.getCityStateZip());
    temp.put("providerPhone",pr.getPhone());
    myList.add(temp);
}

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, myList, R.layout.custom_row_view,
                new String[] {"providerName","providerAddress","providerCityStateZip","providerPhone"},
                new int[] {R.id.providerName,R.id.providerAddress, R.id.providerCityStateZip, R.id.providerPhone}
        );

setListAdapter(adapter);
```

It works fine, EXCEPT for the fact that I have to add a delay like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 90000; i++) {
    sum += 1;
}
```

... before creating the SimpleAdapter, otherwise I get no data in the ListView. It's almost as though the code is running asynchronously, like the adapter is being created and bound before the ArrayList is populated. The more rows I have in each individual HashMap, the longer I need to delay.

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong?

Update: I KNOW that this is not an ideal way of implementing a ListView, so I'm not looking for info on how to do a custom adapter, etc., I'm already doing that. This is just something I was playing around with, and I'm trying to figure out why this EXACT code is behaving the way it is, when there's nothing that should cause it to do so...

Comment: This sounds like a pretty custom listview. You should be extending `BaseAdapter` and use that as a custom adapter.

Comment: Why are you putting things into a hash and then putting the hash into and arraylist? and for your simple adapter, what are he parameters for?

Comment: I know there are a dozen other (better) ways to do this, and the final code won't do things this way... I'm not looking for the best way to create the ListView, I'm curious as to why this exact code is behaving the way it is... If I build the ArrayList manually (i.e. myList.add(temp); myList.add(temp1); myList.add(temp2); ) then the delay isn't needed...

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is that it's not validating until after the for loop. I guess try an invalidate() after the setListAdapter()...

Comment: First of all, thats a crazy way to do a delay, why not just sleep?  There must be something you aren't showing in your code snippet. Nothing you have there would cause anything to be run on a different thread.

Comment: Again, the HOW isn't what I'm concerned with, it's the WHY... the best way to implement a delay doesn't really matter to me. The only code that I haven't shown is how providerArrayList gets populated, but it's just an ArrayList of dead-simple objects with basic get* accessors. You're right, there's nothing there that should cause it to behave like this...

Comment: how is your code getting run/called ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom listView adapter. I've written a small tutorial on how you can do it. There is also a sample source that you can refer to.

http://asimmittal.net/blog/?p=170

Comment: Again, I'm not looking for the best way to implement a custom ListView - I already know how to do this. I'm trying to figure out why this exact bit of code is behaving the way it is, when there's nothing that should cause it to do so. More of a theoretical than practical question, I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the two arrays you pass into the constructor before you use them. Might fix it although it probably shouldn't..